# Localstack Lambda Invoke fails on Windows

Tags: docker, terraform, localstack

I have a problem similar to [Unable to invoke lambda function from localstack via aws cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803878/unable-to-invoke-lambda-function-from-localstack-via-aws-cli), but with a different symptom.  The solution described in that SO does not work for me.

I am running on Windows 10, with the latest versions of Docker, Terraform and LocalStack (as of April/May 2021).  All commands are typed into an Windows `cmd` window with Administrator permissions, set to the correct working folder.

I start local stack using `docker-compose up -d`, with the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack-full:latest
    container_name: localstack_serverless1
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
      - '8055:8080'
    environment:
      # - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
      - START_WEB=1
      #- DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - './.localstack:/tmp/localstack'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
      #- './docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

The lines commented out are things I have tried that didn't make a difference.

I then run `terraform init`, and `terraform apply`, with the following input:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "aws" {
  access_key                  = "mock_access_key"
  region                      = "us-east-1"
  s3_force_path_style         = true
  secret_key                  = "mock_secret_key"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true

  # AWS Provider version held back for this issue:
  # https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1818
  # (localstack's fix not released yet)
  # version = "2.39.0"

  endpoints {
    apigateway     = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudformation = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudwatch     = "http://localhost:4566"
    dynamodb       = "http://localhost:4566"
    ec2            = "http://localhost:4566"
    es             = "http://localhost:4566"
    firehose       = "http://localhost:4566"
    iam            = "http://localhost:4566"
    kinesis        = "http://localhost:4566"
    lambda         = "http://localhost:4566"
    route53        = "http://localhost:4566"
    redshift       = "http://localhost:4566"
    s3             = "http://localhost:4566"
    secretsmanager = "http://localhost:4566"
    ses            = "http://localhost:4566"
    sns            = "http://localhost:4566"
    sqs            = "http://localhost:4566"
    ssm            = "http://localhost:4566"
    stepfunctions  = "http://localhost:4566"
    sts            = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "serverless1_bucket1" {
  bucket = "serverless1-bucket1"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "upload_code_lambda1" {
  bucket = "serverless1-bucket1"
  key    = "v1.0.0/lambda1.zip"
  source = "lambda1.zip"
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.serverless1_bucket1]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "serverless1_lambda1" {
   function_name = "serverless1-lambda1"

   # The bucket name as created earlier with "aws s3api create-bucket"
   s3_bucket = "serverless1-bucket1"
   s3_key    = "v1.0.0/lambda1.zip"

   # "lambda1" is the filename within the zip file (lambda1.js) and "handler"
   # is the name of the property under which the handler function was
   # exported in that file.
   handler = "lambda1.handler"
   runtime = "nodejs10.x"

   role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn
   
   # Ant Waters: I have added this to make lambda creation wait until the code has been uploaded.  I'm not sure if it is needed or not.
   depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_object.upload_code_lambda1]
}

 # IAM role which dictates what other AWS services the Lambda function
 # may access.
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec" {
   name = "serverless_example_lambda"

   assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  name        = "ServerlessExample1"
  description = "Terraform Serverless Application Example"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "proxy" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.root_resource_id
   path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id
   http_method   = "ANY"
   authorization = "NONE"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy.resource_id
   http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy.http_method

   integration_http_method = "POST"
   type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
   uri                     = aws_lambda_function.serverless1_lambda1.invoke_arn
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy_root" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.root_resource_id
   http_method   = "ANY"
   authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.resource_id
   http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.http_method

   integration_http_method = "POST"
   type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
   uri                     = aws_lambda_function.serverless1_lambda1.invoke_arn
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example" {
   depends_on = [
     aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda,
     aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root,
   ]

   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   stage_name  = "test"
}


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
   statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
   action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
   function_name = aws_lambda_function.serverless1_lambda1.function_name
   principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

   # The "/*/*" portion grants access from any method on any resource
   # within the API Gateway REST API.
   source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

output "base_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.invoke_url
}
```

The gateway stuff is copied from a tutorial, and I don't understand it yet.

I can then see the lambda in "https://app.localstack.cloud/resources" and "https://app.localstack.cloud/resources/gateway", and there is an Invoke button on the gateway page.
However, when I press this nothing seems to happen, except an error log in CloudWatch:

[image: ClouWatch error log]

Similarly, I can see the function using the AWS CLI, with the call:

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name "serverless1-lambda1" --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566
```

which returns:

```
{
    "Configuration": {
        "FunctionName": "serverless1-lambda1",
        "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless1-lambda1",
        "Runtime": "nodejs10.x",
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/serverless_example_lambda",
        "Handler": "lambda1.handler",
        "CodeSize": 342,
        "Description": "",
        "Timeout": 3,
        "MemorySize": 128,
        "LastModified": "2021-05-07T10:17:32.305+0000",
        "CodeSha256": "qoP7ORF4AUC8VJWLR0bGGRRKGtNrQwRj2hCa1n+3wk4=",
        "Version": "$LATEST",
        "VpcConfig": {},
        "TracingConfig": {
            "Mode": "PassThrough"
        },
        "RevisionId": "ea163f0f-81ce-4b3a-a0d1-7b44379c6492",
        "State": "Active",
        "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful",
        "PackageType": "Zip"
    },
    "Code": {
        "Location": "http://localhost:4566/2015-03-31/functions/serverless1-lambda1/code"
    },
    "Tags": {}
}
```

However, when I try to invoke it using:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 lambda invoke --function-name "serverless1-lambda1" output.json
```

The return is:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Lambda process returned error status code: 1. Result: . Output:\nUnable to find image 'lambci/lambda:nodejs10.x' locally\nError response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)\nmust specify at least one container source\njson: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type types.ContainerJSON",
  "errorType": "InvocationException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_api.py\", line 602, in run_lambda\n    result = LAMBDA_EXECUTOR.execute(func_arn, func_details, event, context=context,\n",
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 176, in execute\n    return do_execute()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 168, in do_execute\n    return _run(func_arn=func_arn)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py\", line 149, in wrapped\n    raise e\n",
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py\", line 145, in wrapped\n    result = func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 159, in _run\n    raise e\n",
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 147, in _run\n    result = self._execute(func_arn, func_details, event, context, version)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 325, in _execute\n    result = self.run_lambda_executor(cmd, stdin, env_vars=environment, func_details=func_details)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py\", line 231, in run_lambda_executor\n    raise InvocationException('Lambda process returned error status code: %s. Result: %s. Output:\\n%s' %\n"
  ]
}
```

and the Docker window trace shows:

```
localstack_serverless1 | 2021-05-07T10:59:50:WARNING:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Empty event body specified for invocation of Lambda "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless1-lambda1"
localstack_serverless1 | 2021-05-07T10:59:50:INFO:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Running lambda cmd: CONTAINER_ID="$(docker create -i   -e AWS_REGION="$AWS_REGION" -e DOCKER_LAMBDA_USE_STDIN="$DOCKER_LAMBDA_USE_STDIN" -e LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME="$LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME" -e EDGE_PORT="$EDGE_PORT" -e _HANDLER="$_HANDLER" -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT="$AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT" -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME="$AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME" -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION="$AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_VERSION" -e AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_INVOKED_ARN="$AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_INVOKED_ARN" -e AWS_LAMBDA_COGNITO_IDENTITY="$AWS_LAMBDA_COGNITO_IDENTITY" -e NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="$NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"   --rm "lambci/lambda:nodejs10.x" "lambda1.handler")";docker cp "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.9cb3ff88/." "$CONTAINER_ID:/var/task"; docker start -ai "$CONTAINER_ID";
localstack_serverless1 | 2021-05-07T11:00:05:DEBUG:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors: Lambda arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless1-lambda1 result / log output:
localstack_serverless1 | 
localstack_serverless1 | > Unable to find image 'lambci/lambda:nodejs10.x' locally
localstack_serverless1 | > Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
localstack_serverless1 | > must specify at least one container source
localstack_serverless1 | > json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type types.ContainerJSON
localstack_serverless1 | 2021-05-07T11:00:05:INFO:localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_api: Error executing Lambda function arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:function:serverless1-lambda1: Lambda process returned error status code: 1. Result: . Output:
localstack_serverless1 | Unable to find image 'lambci/lambda:nodejs10.x' locally
localstack_serverless1 | Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
localstack_serverless1 | must specify at least one container source
localstack_serverless1 | json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type types.ContainerJSON Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_api.py", line 602, in run_lambda
localstack_serverless1 |     result = LAMBDA_EXECUTOR.execute(func_arn, func_details, event, context=context,
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 176, in execute
localstack_serverless1 |     return do_execute()
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 168, in do_execute
localstack_serverless1 |     return _run(func_arn=func_arn)
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py", line 149, in wrapped
localstack_serverless1 |     raise e
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/cloudwatch/cloudwatch_util.py", line 145, in wrapped
localstack_serverless1 |     result = func(*args, **kwargs)
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 159, in _run
localstack_serverless1 |     raise e
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 147, in _run
localstack_serverless1 |     result = self._execute(func_arn, func_details, event, context, version)
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 325, in _execute
localstack_serverless1 |     result = self.run_lambda_executor(cmd, stdin, env_vars=environment, func_details=func_details)
localstack_serverless1 |   File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/services/awslambda/lambda_executors.py", line 231, in run_lambda_executor
localstack_serverless1 |     raise InvocationException('Lambda process returned error status code: %s. Result: %s. Output:\n%s' %
localstack_serverless1 | localstack.services.awslambda.lambda_executors.InvocationException: Lambda process returned error status code: 1. Result: . Output:
localstack_serverless1 | Unable to find image 'lambci/lambda:nodejs10.x' locally
localstack_serverless1 | Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
localstack_serverless1 | must specify at least one container source
localstack_serverless1 | json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type types.ContainerJSON
localstack_serverless1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by changing docker-compose.yml to the following:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack-full:latest
    container_name: localstack_serverless1
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
      - '4571:4571'
      - '8055:8080'
    environment:
      # - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
      - START_WEB=1
      
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - HOST_TMP_FOLDER=./.localstack
    volumes:
      - './.localstack:/tmp/localstack'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'     # I don't understand what this corresponds to on my PC? But it is the only option I can get to work!
```

The last line is very curious, as I don't understand what that maps to on my windows PC?